# Why converting a flv file to mp3 I got a bigger file?

Tags: sound, mp3, convert, audacity, flv

Converting a flv music file from youtube to mp3 with Audacity I got a bigger file than the initial flv. I guess I have set too big a bit-rate or something like that that has artificially inflated the audio file*. Or is this normal? What is the audio behind a flv?

And what is the proper setting so as to get a sound file that is the one of the "original" flv?

[*Using `ffmpeg -i *.flv` i got some info on the flv audio: `Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 131 kb/s`. While the mp3: `mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 320 kb/s`]

(Installing ffmpeg and using `ffmpeg -i input_file.flv output_file.mp3` I get an mp3 that is half the flv. Is this the way?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It possibly happens because by default Audacity exports mp3 files with 192Kbps even if the original quality of the file was lower. Try using a lower value.

Comment: i had even set a bigger bitrate, indeed. 
Using `ffmpeg -i *.flv` i got some info on the flv audio: `Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 131 kb/s`. While the mp3: `mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 320 kb/s`

Answer (score 1):

Often times when converting a file to mp3, in gets covered in a .wav. wrapper.

The “.wav” file is just a wrapper for audio data.  As such a “.wav” file can contain compressed audio data.  For example, we could imagine audio data compressed with the MP3 codec being stored in a “.wav” wrapper. It all depends on the codec used on the audio data the Wav format has to wrap, but this wrapper can increase the size slightly. Although wrapped in Wav, it will still shows up as mp3.

One possible reason why you see an increase in size.